# Is it possible to create a browser extension to allow for incoming requests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am looking to figure out a way to make incoming request to a browser.  Installing an extension in the browser is OK.  The goal of this is to allow another machine to connect to the extension to control a game without needing an intermediary server.

Is this feasible?  Is it possible to make a Chrome or Firefox extension open a port to allow for incoming request?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for are server sockets. For Chrome the answer is "no", Chrome extensions can only open client connections. Firefox extensions on the other hand can use [`nsIServerSocket` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocket) to listen for incoming TCP connections on a port. If you use the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) you would need to use the [`chrome` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html). Something like this:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var socket = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/server-socket;1"]
               .createInstance(Ci.nsIServerSocket);
socket.init(12345, false, -1);
socket.asyncListen({
  onSocketAccepted: function(socket, transport)
  {
    ...
  },
  onStopListening: function(socket, status)
  {
  }
});
```