# Can I send data between clients on same network when there is no internet connection with HTML5?

Tags: html, mobile, offline

I want to build a restaurant automation web application that uses HTML5 and ASP.NET. Also, mobile clients(android, iPhone etc.) will use small part of that application.

There are a main client and some mobile clients( to receive orders from clients) in a restaurant. They are on the same network and will run my web app on browser. I will know their local ip addresses. When offline, my application can works because it uses offline property of html5.

If there is no internet connection, can mobile clients send their data to main client?
When connection is available there is no problem, but when offline mobiles must send data to main. After online, i can sync data with server. İ dont want to write small exe that runs on main client and receiving from mobile clients.

I can make android,iOS,win app for clients if I pass this problem.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: 'no internet connection' also means 'no wireless connection'?

Comment: Ethrbunny, there is wireless connection but not internet. Clients can communicate with each other. They can access others by ip addresses. But i dont want to write an exe for main client. Can i use offline web app instead of exe?

Comment: This really sounds like a 'client/server' model to me. The 'offline web app' won't be able to talk to the other clients since it's a client itself and 'offline'. Create an 'asp' server on one machine and handle the values from all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Probably i build adobe air or exe app, communicate networked clients and when internet connection available it sync itself with web db. :(

Comment: one alternative?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787514/is-it-possible-to-create-a-browser-extension-to-allow-for-incoming-requests